# retrieving code from a Texas Instruments C200 DSPs

Tags: c++, c, assembly, signal-processing, 32-bit

Does anyone know how to retrieve code from a Texas Instruments DSP processor? I'm using a TMS320LF2407 DSP, and I need to access the program on the chip, most likely using the JTAG connector. Any help would be appreciated. I've contacted TI, they were no help. I found SPRA830 that talks about using C code to copy blocks of program code to memory, but none of the associated files are available.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the jtag then you should be able to connect to it with TI's Code Composer Studio. This also assumes that you have a supported JTAG emulator box which are fairly expensive. I think the biggest problem is going to be finding out what memory addresses are being used for code vs RAM. Can you give more details about what you're trying to do? Is this some specific hardware or is it an eval board?

Comment: Knowing what menu option to use in Code Composer Studio to use to establish a JTAG connection *without overwriting the existing flash memory content* would probably be helpful.

Comment: I haven't seen anything in default CCS connect settings that overwrites flash. The safest thing to do is to make sure that you're not loading a gel file that does some automatic stuff when you connect

Comment: It's for work. Code was lost for an old piece of equipment so I was attempting to retrieve it. But I suddenly get the feeling that it may be protected on the chip... Nothing in CC studio about retrieving it though...

Comment: Have you tried JTAG connecting to the device and viewing memory? You would need to know the memory ranges that the device uses. If it all runs from flash or ROM the PC register will obviously have a memory location that is somewhere in the code range when you connect.